# Is there a reason public is included in gatsby's gitignore?

Tags: gatsby

I want to add a title and description meta tag for my `index.html` page in my public folder to improve SEO but gatsby has `index.html` in its `gitignore` file. Is it ok for me to remove `index.html` from `gitignore` without breaking anything? Is there a different way to update `index.html` without having it reset every time I push through git?

Comment: I have a similar issue where I need to use `user-select: none;` embedded in the `index.html` file. The below answer gets me no closer. A hacky solution is therefore on the horizon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The public folder is created by Gatsby on each build and if you add anything to the public folder, it will be overriden when the build runs next time

As per the [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-project-structure/#folders)

> **/public** Automatically generated. The output of the build process will be exposed inside this folder. Should be added to the
>   **.gitignore** file if not added already.

In order to add page metadata such as description and title, Gatsby recommends to use react-helment

According to [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/seo/#page-metadata)

> Adding metadata to pages, such as page title, meta description, alt
>   text and structured data using JSON-LD, helps search engines
>   understand your content and when to show your pages in search results.
>
> A common way to add metadata to pages is to add `react-helmet`
>   components (together with the Gatsby React Helmet plugin for SSR
>   support) to your page components.

Comment: How to use the Helmet equivalent of `<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">`?  Cannot find it in the docs anywhere.